# Merge cells does not work while creating pdf using PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, mpdf

I am trying to create a PDF document using PHPexcel and mPDF as rendering engine.It generates an error "This PDF document might not be viewed correctly" when using the following code to merge cells.

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:A3');
```

Has anybody experienced this error?

Simmy

Answer (score 1):

Quick and Dirty fix;

Change line 1236 of PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php, which reads:

```
$cssClass .= ' style' . $pSheet->getCell($endCellCoord)->getXfIndex();
```

to

```
if (!$this->_useInlineCss) {
    $cssClass .= ' style' . $pSheet->getCell($endCellCoord)->getXfIndex();
}
```